# Unable to support mongodb+srv// style connections as the 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory' class is not available in this JRE

Tags: java, mongodb, jetty, resteasy, morphia

I'm trying to make an API in java using resteasy and jetty to run the API and Morphia to connect to a MongoDB database, however when I try to create a datastore the application crashes and gives the following errors:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Unable to support mongodb+srv// style connections as the 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory' class is not available in this JRE. A JNDI context is required for resolving SRV records.
  at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
```

I'm using java 11 for this.

If more info is needed I will try to provide it.